# Use set of "Recent Changes" within build

Tags: git, jenkins, jenkins-plugins

I have a continuous build which checks out the code from git. I would like to further use the list of changes within the build.

I know for a fact that the [Email-ext Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Email-ext+plugin) provides exactly this functionality through environment variables like `CHANGES_SINCE_LAST_SUCCESS` or `CHANGES_SINCE_LAST_UNSTABLE`.

When I install the plugin, will those environment variables also be available in my other build steps?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, they won't be available. Those are not environment variables, but rather tokens that have meaning within EmailExt plugin only.

You can get that info yourself programatically with a Groovy script that is run via [Groovy Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Groovy+plugin) and utilizes [Jenkins Java API](http://javadoc.jenkins-ci.org/).

Answer (score 0):

I got something like this working for darcs, like this. A key piece here is that darcs sets some useful environment variables that a "post hook" functions can use for notifications like this. If you can find a way to initialize an equivalent environment variable for git, then you are set!

```
curl -X HEAD http://ci.example.com/job/my_job/build && sleep 5 && echo description="<pre>$DARCS_PATCHES</pre>" | curl -X POST --data-binary @- http://ci.example.com/job/my_job/lastBuild/submitDescription
```

Ideally there would be a way to do this more elegantly with the Jenkin's REST API, but I couldn't find it. So first, a build is triggered. Then we sleep for a few seconds, because the build request is asynchronous. Finally, the build description is updated with the list of recent changes provided by darcs.